# Can't connect in php to db in postgres-docker-container

Tags: php, database, postgresql, docker

I have a debian wheezy server with apache2. The database is a docker container - standard postgres:9.1 with Port 5432 exposed to localhost:5434, data folder is in an own container connected via -v option.

Data-Container

```
docker run --name db-data -v /data -e PGDATA=/data -it --entrypoint /bin/bash postgres:9.1
```

Database-Container

```
docker run -d --name db -e POSTGRES_USER=name -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pwd \
  -e PGDATA=/data -p 5434:5432 --volumes-from db-data postgres:9.1
```

I use a simple php script to test the connection:

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5434 dbname=name user=name password=pwd connect_timeout=5");
if ($db) {
  echo pg_options($db);
} else {
  echo "error";
}
```

### Issue

When I run this script via `php info.php`, I got following error after short waiting time:

```
PHP Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: 
 timeout expired in /var/www/start/info.php on line 2
```

- I can connect via VPN and pgadmin from remote and local via telnet localhost 5434.
- Also `nmap -p 5434 localhost` returns, that this Port is open.
- I have installed `php5-pgsql`.
- docker logs ... has no entries, even in fully debug mode

I would really appreciate any input!

Comment: what does ```docker logs name-of-your-postgres-container``` say?

Comment: have you looked at the logs of the PostgreSQL container ? Just `docker logs id_pgsql`should show a few things . And you can get into the container with `docker exec -it id_pgsql bash` and debug locally

Comment: activated debug logging via postgresql.conf, but nothing shows up, related to my connection tries...

Comment: just for completeness sake can you also provide the ```docker run``` command you used to create your container?

Comment: is now in the question...

Comment: This blog could be useful if you try to connect with php to postgres using env vars: https://lvthillo.com/create-simple-php-app-using-postgresql-in-docker-compose/

Comment: Is PHP also running in a container?